# how to find the inner elements when all div class name and span class name are same using jsoup in java

Tags: java, jsoup

```
<div class="xyOfqd">
   <div class="hAyfc">
     <div class="BgcNfc">Updated</div>
       <span class="htlgb">
          <div>
             <span class="htlgb">July 14, 2018</span>
          </div>
       </span>
     </div>
   <div class="hAyfc">
     <div class="BgcNfc">Size</div>
     <span class="htlgb">
        <div><span class="htlgb">3.9M</span></div>
     </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want all the text from above html using jsoup in java.

Like this
Updated
July 14, 2018
Size
3.9M

updated and size are constant but date and 3.9M are dynamic values.

Basically I am trying to scrap the values from google play store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues here:

1. Finding the CSS selector of elements with the same name. This is the easier part, because they all have a different selector. If you use your browser's developer tools you will see that the selector of `update` is `div.hAyfc:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)` and the selctor of `size` is `div.hAyfc:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1)`.
2. Getting dynamic values - well, Jsoup cannot get dynamic values. You can try to find the `ajax` call that fetches those values and try to do the same with Jsoup, or use some other tool, like PhantomJS